# Is it Possible that to pass Byte Array image from Database to SSRS Report in c# windows application

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, desktop-application

Below is my Database Table :
[image: Database_Image_Table]

I developing C# Desktop application and here i need to show the Image of Byte Array of Database in SSRS/Crystal report , but here i don't wants that first Save the image in Folder and then pass the path of the Image to the report , But i wants that to show the image in report without passing the path.

Comment: i am assuming, you are using MS-SQL right?

Comment: look at this article it it'll help you out https://www.codeproject.com/articles/128657/how-do-i-use-sql-file-stream